# React Native - optional values for firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a custom hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import firebase from "../../firebase";

export default function useCurrentUserDetails() {
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid;
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!uid) {
            setData(null);
            return;
        }

        const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists) {
                setData(snapshot.data());
            } else {
                setData(null);
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [uid]);

    const updateCurrentUserData = (newData) => 
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).set(newData).then(() => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Profile Updated',
                'Nice work!',
                [
                { text: 'OK' }
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
            );
        }).catch((error) => {
            Alert.alert(
                'Something went wrong',
                'Give it another go',
                [
                { text: 'OK' }
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
            );
        });
 
    return [data, updateCurrentUserData];
}
```

In my view im calling the following:

```
const [currentUserDetails, setCurrentUserDetails] = useCurrentUserDetails();
```

And on a button press, the values are updated:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        const url = await uploadImage(profileURL, firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        await setCurrentUserDetails(
            { ...currentUserDetails, 
                username, 
                age: Number(age), 
                height,
                country,
                occupation,
                profileURL: url,
            }
        )
        setLoading(false)
    }
```

The issue im having is that for the first time the user try's to edit the data, it won't update unless I have all the fields present. How could I make each value `optional`?

For example lets say the person only updated the `occupation` it will update it and leave the rest and not create any fields for this in the db.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if how I did this is a correct approach.

y is destructured into separate fields.

```js
const updateUserProfile = (y) => {
    const { Age, Hobby, UserName, Job, Country, Name } = y;
    return firestore.collection("users").doc(`${currentUser.uid}`).update({
      UserName: UserName,
      Hobby: Hobby,
      Name: Name,
      Age: Age,
      Country: Country,
      Job: Job,
    });
  };
```

This way I can update any field I want. But in my case all of these fields already have
default data written, like UserName : UserName, Hobby: hobby. And then I update it with what user changed.

This is how I get "y"
userData is what I get from firestore.

```js
 const [data, setData] = useState({ [name]: value });

const x = userData;
  const y = Object.assign(x, data);
```

Sorry if that is a mess of a answer.

Comment: "But in my case all of these fields already have default data written" - This helped, I assigned default values and its all working good

Comment: Atleast something haha.